# Two series diverge simultaneously (Müntz-Szász theorem for $L^2[0, 1]$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am currently reading the proof of the Müntz-Szász theorem for $L^2[0, 1]$ on page 6 of [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a856/08402bfcc3a80dfc0e934a0e7eb0be8dcb0f.pdf) and I'm stuck at this point:

We have a sequence $(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of real numbers with $\lambda_i > -1/2$ for every $i$ and a fixed natural number $m$ different from every $\lambda_i,$ and the authors claim that
$$ \sum_{\substack{i= 1 \\ \lambda_i > m}}^\infty \frac{2m+1}{m+\lambda_i+1}=+\infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{\substack{i= 1 \\ \lambda_i > m}}^\infty \frac{1}{2\lambda_i + 1} = +\infty.$$

Now, I see that $\Longleftarrow$ is true, because
$$\frac{2m+1}{m+\lambda_i+1} \geq \frac{2m +1}{2\lambda_i +1}$$
for all $i$ with $\lambda_i > m,$ but I haven't been able to prove the other implication. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: $m+\lambda_{i}+ 1 > \lambda_{i}+ \frac{1}{2} >0$ so $\frac{2m+1}{m+\lambda_i+1} <  2\frac{2m +1}{2\lambda_i +1}$